# html email signature padding/alignment issues

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

Trying to get an email signature working, but cannot get the image part to sit flush against the table column, appears to be white space/padding at the bottom and right side. Below is the code Im using, looks fine in a browser but not mail (outlook)

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>J.Clarke</title>
    <style>
    .btmStrip{
     /*border:1px solid red;
     padding-bottom:50px;
     background: linear-gradient(bottom, #000 70%, #fff 70%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #000 70%, #fff 70%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #000 70%, #fff 70%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #000 70%, #fff 70%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #000 70%, #fff 70%); */
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-spacing:0;">
      <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td width="118">&nbsp;</td>
       <td width="62">&nbsp;</td>
       <td colspan="3" rowspan="2" style="text-align:right;padding-right:5%;"><a href="http://name.co.za/" target="_blank"><img src="logo1.jpg" width="131" height="90" alt="co name"/></a></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td colspan="3"><span style="vertical-align:text-top; font-size:14px;font-family:'Montserrat Ultra Light';">Warm Regards,</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td colspan="4"></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
       <td width="118" style="height:0px; background-color: #fff;line-height:0px"></td>
       <td width="62" style="height:0px; background-color: #fff;line-height:0px"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="background-color:#fff;">
       <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="text-align:left;"></td>
       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="background-color:#000;">
       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="background-color:#000;">
       <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center;"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="background-color:#fff;">
       <td colspan="2" rowspan="17" align="right" valign="bottom"><img style="display:block" src="http://overit.co.za/tst.jpg" width="180" height="175" alt=""/></td>
       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;">
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="background-color:#fff;">
       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="background-color:#fff;">
       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;">&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="background-color:#000;">
       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;">
     
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="background-color:#000;">
       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="background-color:#000;">
       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="background-color:#fff;">
       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;padding:0px 5px;"><hr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000; background-color:#000;margin-left: 0px;"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="background-color:#000;">
       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="background-color:#fff;">
       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;padding-bottom:2px;"><span style="font-family:'Montserrat Ultra Light'; vertical-align:text-top; font-size:16px;"><span style="font-family:'Montserrat SemiBold';">Name Name</span>  |  <a style="text-decoration:none;color:#282828;" href="mailto:name@name.co.za" target="_blank">name@name.co.za</a>  |  <a style="text-decoration:none;color:#282828;" href="http://name.co.za/" target="_blank">www.name.co.za</a> </span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="background-color:#000;">
       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;" height="11px"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="background-color:#000;">
       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;"><span style="font-family:'Montserrat Ultra Light'; color:#fff;font-size:10px;"><span style="font-family:'Montserrat SemiBold';">name</span>  |  031 031031031  |  <a style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;" href="mailto:kloof@satincandy.co.za" target="_blank">name@name.co.za</a>  |  <span style="font-family:'Montserrat SemiBold';">name</span>  |  031 031031031  |  <a style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;" href="mailto:dnorth@name.co.za" target="_blank">dnorth@name.co.za</a></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="background-color:#000;">
       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;"></td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="background-color:#000;">
       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;" height="25px">&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
    <!--    <tr style="background-color:#000;">
       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;" height="28.75px">&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>-->
    <!--    <tr style="background-color:#000;">
       <td colspan="2" style="text-align:right;" height="28.75px">&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>-->
     <tr style="background-color:#000;">
       <td width="415" height="18.75px" style="text-align:right;">&nbsp;</td>
       <td width="105" style="text-align:right;" height="18.75px">&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
     <tr style="background-color:#000;">
       <td style="text-align:right; padding-bottom:10px;" height="30px"><span style="color:#fff; font-family:'Montserrat Ultra Light';"><span style="color:#d7ab64; font-family:'Montserrat Regular'; font-size:80%;"><a style="text-decoration:none;color:#d7ab64;" href="http://satincandy.co.za/" target="_blank">SHOP NOW</a></span>  |  <a style="text-decoration:none;color:#fff;font-size:80%;" href="http://satincandy.co.za/" target="_blank">SIGN UP TO OUR NEWSLETTER</a></span></td>
       <td width="105" style="text-align:left;padding-right:15px;padding-bottom:10px;" height="30px"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com"><img data-class="external" src="instagram.png" align="right"></a>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img data-class="external" src="pintrest.png" align="right"></a>
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img data-class="external" src="facebook.png" align="right"></a>
       <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img data-class="external" src="twitter.png" align="right"></a></td>
     </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a screen shot of what it looks like in outlook.

Comment: @Zze thanks, here is a screen shot:  https://postimg.org/image/3llyqt7jl/  and this is how it should look: https://postimg.org/image/vezxjrq47/

Answer (score 0):

Its the column and row span that is causing the issue. Try this code:

```html
    <table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:180px;padding-bottom:20px;">Warm regards</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:180px;">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#000000" height="2"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    
         </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:180px;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;"><span style="font-family:'Montserrat SemiBold';">loren loren loren loren loren</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#000000"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="180" align="left" valign="top"><img src="http://placehold.it/180x150/000000/ffffff/?text=Logo+Goes+Here" width="180" height="150" /></td>
                <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-top:50px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#000000">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="text-align:right; padding-bottom:10px;" height="30px">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td style="text-align:left;padding-right:15px;padding-bottom:10px;" height="30px">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="text-align:right; padding-bottom:10px;" height="30px"><span style="color:#fff; font-family:'Montserrat Ultra Light';"><span style="color:#d7ab64; font-family:'Montserrat Regular'; font-size:80%;">loren loren loren loren loren</span></td>
                      <td width="105" style="text-align:left;padding-right:15px;padding-bottom:10px;" height="30px"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com"> <img data-class="external" src="instagram.png" align="right" /> </a> <a target="_blank" href="#"> <img data-class="external" src="pintrest.png" align="right" /> </a> <a target="_blank" href="#"> <img data-class="external" src="facebook.png" align="right" /> </a> <a target="_blank" href="#"> <img data-class="external" src="twitter.png" align="right" /> </a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="text-align:right; padding-bottom:10px;" height="30px">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td style="text-align:left;padding-right:15px;padding-bottom:10px;" height="30px">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I recoded and removed the row span and col span. you can add and remove anything from the code.

Comment: I dont see you utilizing the image in your code? thanks

Comment: Do you mean the big black image on the left? I removed it as you can work without it. The spacing on the left is handled by padding and background colour.

Comment: the image was just a placeholder image, as I cant show the real image. There needs to be an image present, the problem lies in the padding/spacing between the image and the columns

Comment: I have added an image placeholder now so it should give you a space of 180px to add in an image. let me know if that helps.

Comment: thanks for the assistance its close to what I'm after, but this is exactly what Im trying to accomplish (re-edited above) with making sure that the black of the image lines up with the table to the rows, with no spacing between image and columns: http://imgur.com/g9kaOQl

Comment: I changed the code a little to reflect the look you were after. You should be able to adjust the padding and image now.

Comment: unfortunately not if you use the same placeholder image I used you will see the background color on the top and side, I also tried applying a background color originally but it wont work.

Comment: you will need to play around with the image you are placing as well. It has to be half white background and half black. Next will be changing the padding on the right column for alignment with the black background.

or you can add a half white and half black background image and put in a transparent png for the logo and adjust the padding on right column to align the black area.